# SQL Server 2008: Finding strings within a table which contain the word World

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to filter my query to show only table entries with the word WORLD and also contains other country codes.

I have used the wildcard function but I am unsure as to how I can have it only return entries with both WORLD and other country codes.

```
SELECT *
FROM [****].[dbo].[Titles]
WHERE Territories LIKE '%world%'
```

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: Expected result would return all rows with both WORLD and one or more country code in the field. The territories column in this table contains both World or country codes and should bot contain both. the reason im running this query is to search for any rows with bad data.

Comment: can you post sample data and expected result?

Comment: Is country code a different column?  Please post your table schema.

Comment: What are the possible values in the Territories column? Please give some examples of what you want to be selected and what should not be selected.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM [****].[dbo].[Titles]
WHERE Territories LIKE '%world%'
AND Territories LIKE '%countryCode%'
```

but I am not sure how fast that will be. If you know that the other country codes will always come after the world code, you could do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM [****].[dbo].[Titles]
WHERE Territories LIKE '%world%countryCode%'
```

which I think should run faster.

Comment: I agree, if you know they come after and are not mutually exclusive of one another, that would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it can contain other country codes and world then you need

```
WHERE Territories LIKE '%world%' AND Territories LIKE '%{other country code}%'
```

If you are looking at world or other country code you need

```
WHERE Territories LIKE '%world%' OR Territories LIKE '%{other country code}%'
```